# Difference between tcp_write and tcp_output functions

Tags: lwip

What is the difference between `tcp_write()` and `tcp_output()` functions in lwIP v1.4.1 (raw API)?

The `tcp_write()` function enqueues data for transmission and the `tcp_ouput()` function forces all enqueued data to be sent.

I noticed that the `tcp_write()` function also sends data without `tcp_output()` function.

Comment: A quick look through messages on this subject indicates that `tcp_output()` lets lwip know that you're done making `tcp_write()` calls for now, and that it can transmit the accumulated packet immediately, rather than waiting for any additional writes.  In other words, its use is solely a matter of efficiency, rather than correctness of operation.

Comment: Thank you! That is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

tcp_write() waits in the expectation of more data being sent soon (as it can send them more efficiently by combining them together).
To prompt the system to send data now, call tcp_output() after calling tcp_write().